# React button component with a conditional is not working and displaying

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem with a conditional ReactJS component.
I've created a component with where if a visitor clicks on the button it would display more information.

It would be really awesome if someone could help me what did I do wrong and explained that to me (that would be really awesome).

Thank you.

```
function SimpleButton(params) {
  return (
      <button onClick={props.onClick}>
          Show content
      </button>
  );
}

function ExtendedButton(params) {
  button (
      <button onClick={props.onClick}>
          <div>
              <p>Displays content</p>
          </div>
      </button>
  );
}

class QuoteButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.hideDisplay = this.hideDisplay.bind(this);
      this.showDisplay = this.showDisplay.bind(this);
      this.state = {revealed: false}
  }

  hideDisplay() {
      this.setState({revealed: true});
  }

  showDisplay() {
      this.setState({revealed: false});
  }

  render() {
      const revealed = this.state.revealed;
      let button;
      if (revealed) {
          button = <SimpleButton onClick={this.hideDisplay} />;
      } else {
          button = <ExtendedButton onClick={this.showDisplay} />;
      }

      return (
        <div>
          <ExtendingButton revealed = {revealed} />
          {button}
        </div>
      );
  }
}
```

Comment: need a `return` in `render()`

Comment: From where you are getting this `simpleButton` ?

Comment: Can you please write the `extendedButton` function inside the class component. I think it may be worked.

Comment: as mentioned @diedu, you are missing `return`. Besides you need use Capital name for your components https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized

Comment: I've added:    return (
        <div>
          <ExtendingButton revealed = {revealed} />
          {button}
        </div>
      );   in the render(), but it's still not displaying anything

Comment: Both of your functional components above accept `params` parameter, but try to operate inside the function some `props` undefined variable. Have you checked the console whether there are any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const SimpleButton = (props) => (
  <button onClick={props.onClick}>Show content</button>
);

const ExtendedButton = (props) => (
  <button onClick={props.onClick}>
    <div>
      <p>Displays content</p>
    </div>
  </button>
);

class QuoteButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.hideDisplay = this.hideDisplay.bind(this);
    this.showDisplay = this.showDisplay.bind(this);
    this.state = { revealed: false };
  }

  hideDisplay() {
    this.setState({ revealed: true });
  }

  showDisplay() {
    this.setState({ revealed: false });
    console.log(this.state);
  }

  render() {
    const revealed = this.state.revealed;
    return !revealed ? (
      <SimpleButton onClick={this.hideDisplay} />
    ) : (
      <ExtendedButton onClick={this.showDisplay} />
    );
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your `QuoteButton` component doesn't recognize `button` as it is not coming from state or props. Try this in place of `{button}`:

```
{
  !!revealed ? <SimpleButton onClick={this.hideDisplay} /> :
    <ExtendedButton onClick={this.showDisplay} />
}
```

Also, check out this StackBlitz [snipp](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-sdttfj) for more.